# MailAddressCollection.Add() only sometimes chokes on periods

Tags: asp.net, .net, integration-testing

We encountered a bug in our production code wherein an email address display name wasn't being properly quoted. This effectively demonstrates the broken code:

```
var recipients = new MailAddressCollection();
var address = "Mr. Smith <mr.smith@example.com>";
recipients.Add(address);
```

And, as it probably should, it throws a `FormatException` in production -- an ASP.NET site. Adding quotes around the display name portion seems to solve the problem in production:

```
var address = "\"Mr. Smith\" <mr.smith@example.com>";
```

But in testing, no exception is thrown. And our SMTP abstraction is properly invoked.

**Why doesn't the format problem raise an exception during testing / outside the context of IIS?**

---

**Addendum:** We realized our server is still on .NET 3.5, whereas the test project compiles into .NET 4.0.

Is there any evidence to suggest that the 3.5 version of the method was broken? (Or "different.")

---

The backstory, for your entertainment: A bug was reported wherein users with periods in their names were not receiving any of their emails (password resets, new product notifications, etc.). Our initial assumption was that this email address parsing step needed additional escaping or quoting. So, my efforts were focused on adding a handful of tests prove that; but, they proved the opposite: They showed that escaping made no difference.

After over a day of adding tests upon tests to find the point at which adding a period of the name mattered, I asked a couple other developers to help me out -- one of them brilliantly implemented the fix regardless of what the test showed, and it seems to have worked.

We still have no idea why the relevant tests doesn't properly fail.

Comment: Are you sure it is not the mail server which is balking at the address format?  I don't think I have ever had to do your workaround.  I just tried it in a Console application both in debug and not and could not reproduce the format exception.

Comment: If `MailAddressCollection` is aware of the mail server (from web.config?), then it *could* be. But, the format exception is being thrown on `recipients.Add(address)`. And it goes away when we quote the display name portion.

Comment: Looking at the MailAddressCollection source via http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/net/System/Net/mail/MailAddressCollection.cs may help.  Specifically, you may want to look at http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/net/System/Net/mail/MailAddressParser.cs

Comment: The documentation on MSDN explicitly states that it throws the exception: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144695(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Looks like it's coming up via `Add()` through a `ParseAddress()` method ... ?

Comment: Yes -- and according to the MSDN link, a format exception is *only* thrown when: `If multiple e-mail addresses separated with a semicolon character (";") are passed in the addresses parameter. a FormatException exception is raised.`

Comment: I would speculate that your error report was inaccurate, and that the exception is thrown for names including a **comma** or **semicolon**. Either would produce a FormatException, in the first case by being interpreted as an address separator, and in the second, as an *invalid* address separator.

Comment: It may be notable that our server is running .NET 3.5. ... The exception coming from the `Add()` method. No sense denying that, really. That's where the debugger stops. Wrapping a try-catch around *that one line* stops the exception and omits the "malformatted" address. Etc. ... Stop being anti-helpful, please.

Comment: Is it possible that you have an e-mail address with a ; in it?  This would cause the problem.

Comment: Nope. I can reproduce it in production code by setting a user's first name to "Mr." -- which results in an address of the form `Mr. Soandso <whatever@example.com>` -- that's the exact format the debugger shows me as well. No additional characters, separators, etc.

Comment: The only other notable difference (other than ... you know, the whole environment), which I didn't realize was different until about 30 minutes ago, is .NET version. The tests run through .NET 4, the server is still on 3.5.

Comment: Please take a look at the **actual source** link to the System.Net.MailAddressCollection.  You will see that the comments clearly state that the quotes ARE OPTIONAL of the ParseDisplayName method.

Comment: Please note that "the actual source" pertains to a version of .NET that we're not using ... as I said above.

Comment: I wonder if .NET 3.5 worked differently - I just realized you are on 3.5.  That has to be it.